# Replace Date in Pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I'm trying to get an accurate timestamp from a pandas dataframe. My file has the time stamp in seconds since the start of the day, and each file has the date in the filename. I have been able to convert the seconds to hours and minutes using:
    `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sec'], unit='s')`
however the YYMMDD starts at the epoch. I know that timestamp has a replace function, but I have been unsuccessful in getting that to work. Is it possible to get something like this to work?

```
df['month']=month
df['day'] = day
df['year'] = 2018
date = '%s-%s-%s '%(year, month, day) + df['sec']
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(date, unit='s')
```

Or how can I change the timestamp to still have the hours/minutes/seconds I want but to change the date based on the filename/other columns?

Comment: Please post a small sample input and desired output.  See [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could convert your second column to nano-seconds and add the amount of nanoseconds by adding the `pd.Timestamp` value of that date.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['sec']*(10**9) + pd.Timestamp('the date').value)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Suppose we have a filename such as
fname = '2018-01-01.txt'

# Create a csv-file with col sec and values 0,1000,2000
with open(fname,'w') as f:
    f.write('sec\n0\n1000\n2000')       

# Read dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(fname)

# Create datetime column (fname[:-4] = '2018-01-01')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sec']*(10**9) + pd.Timestamp(fname[:-4]).value)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
    sec            datetime
0     0 2018-01-01 00:00:00
1  1000 2018-01-01 00:16:40
2  2000 2018-01-01 00:33:20
```